# 461Forbidden {"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]} using Java

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing **Twitter Rest** example. In this example, I am looking to call Twitter REST API's. When I run the below program I see the error. Could you please let me know what is the issue ?

```
public class JavaRestTweet {
    static String consumerKeyStr = "RSvE3XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    static String consumerSecretStr = "nKEWRoOcIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    static String accessTokenStr = "1371430742-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    static String accessTokenSecretStr = "6ofNXMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OAuthConsumer oAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKeyStr, consumerSecretStr);
        oAuthConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessTokenStr, accessTokenSecretStr);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Hello%20Twitter%20World.");

        oAuthConsumer.sign(httpPost);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(statusCode + ':' + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
461 Forbidden
{"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what you need to know:

> SSL is required

The problem appears to be that you are using http:// instead of https:// in your code:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var oauth_consumer_key = "your consumer key;
    var oauth_consumer_secret = "secret key";

    if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
    {
        OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
            oauth_consumer_key,
            oauth_consumer_secret,
            Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

        Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}",
            reqToken.Token));
    }
    else
    {
        string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
        string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();
        var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
             oauth_consumer_key,
             oauth_consumer_secret,
             requestToken,
             pin);
        OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
        {
            AccessToken = tokens.Token,
            AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
            ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
            ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
        };
        //uncomment for get likes and retweet count
       //var response = TwitterStatus.Show(accesstoken,Convert.ToDecimal(post id), new StatusUpdateOptions() { UseSSL = true, APIBaseAddress = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/" });

        TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(accesstoken, "Posting This Tweet From Asp.Net Website using REST API", new StatusUpdateOptions() { UseSSL = true, APIBaseAddress = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/" });
       var obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ToString());
        var id = (string)obj["id"].ToString();
    }
```